# Do the subfields preserve unity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, extension-field

I have a question:

> Let $F$ and $K$ fields such that $F\subset K$. Can we conclude that $1_K=1_F$?

I found any counterexaples when $F$ and $k$ are rings, but not necessarily fields. However when these are fields I don't get conclude nothing...

Comment: It is built into the definition that the $1$ is the same. This is also done with rings with $1$. Perhaps the example that you mention with rings is in a context (a book or author) that considers rings without a $1$. To distinguish this case, some use the name [rng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rng_(algebra)).

Comment: @plop: one doesn't have to consider rings without $1$ for such a containment. Indeed, if $R$ is a ring with a nontrivial idempotent $e \in R$, then $Re$ is likewise a ring with identity $e$, and we clearly have $Re \subset R$. Of course, $Re$ is not a *subring* of $R$ by definition, as you point out. Your comment addresses the title question of the OP, but the body appears to be asking a slightly different question.

Comment: @AlexWertheim: what definition of **field** do you have in mind that does not involve $1$?

Comment: I think I was expressing myself wrong. When I mentioned the case of rings, I was referring to rings that have unity. I found that certain rings with a unit may contain some sub-ring with a different unit. This made me wonder if the same could happen with the fields ...

Comment: @RobArthan I have no idea what you mean, since I did not say anything in my comment which would suggest that I think there is a definition of field which does not involve 1. My point was that one may reasonably ask whether there are fields $F, K$ such that $F$ is a subset of $K$ (and inherits multiplication operation from $K$), but does not share the same identity as $K$ - this question is different from whether $F$ can be a subfield of $K$ but no share the same identity, which is prohibited by definition.

Comment: I think you should clarify what you mean by $F \subset K$. I think you mean that the inclusion of $F$ in $K$ is a homomorphism of rngs (see first comment of @plop, for the meaning rng). If that is the case, then the homomorphism will also be a homomorphism of rings and hence fields.

Comment: @AlexWertheim: see my second comment: you were reading too much into the statement "$F \subset K$". The OP needs to clarify that.

Answer (score 3):

$1_F \cdot 1_K = 1_F$ by definition of $1_K.$ Also $1_F =1_F\cdot 1_F$ by definition of $1_F.$ Thus $1_F\cdot 1_K =1_F \cdot 1_F.$ Since $1_F\neq 0_F$ by definition of a field, there is an inverse element $1_F^{-1}$ and multiplication with it from the left yields $1_K=1_F.$

No definition necessary. It already follows from the field axioms.

Comment: Indeed. One can also conclude this directly from $1_{F} = 1_{F}^{2}$, since $K$ does not have any nontrivial idempotents, and so we must have $1_{F} = 1_{K}$.

Comment: I think you are making assumptions about what the OP means by $F \subseteq K$.

Comment: You are very right! ... I was thinking to use the fact that the fields dosen't have divisors of 0 and use the inverses, but I didn't find the suited relation